# How does one deal with "read FPDMA QUEUED" error?

Tags: boot, command-line, login

Last night my Ubuntu 18 was fine although it was running a bit laggier than usual. After work, logged it off. The next morning I couldn't login since it goes into a black screen after entering the correct password and goes back to the login. I've tried logging in the login shell but I've had no luck as it does the same thing. I've managed to capture a picture of the error before it goes back to the shell login after entering the correct password. How does one fix this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue (disk / disk controller / cable)

Comment: I would boot a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media, note I'm assuming desktop/server as I'm less familiar with Iot appliances that use Ubuntu Core 18), and check the SMART health status of your hdd/ssd (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  I can't help with appliances though (Ubuntu Core 18's intended audience)

Comment: Typically, an I/O error indicates either a faulty connection with your disk internally, or a dead disk.  Usually it is an indicator of drive death, at the hardware level.

Comment: @ThomasWard Oh I see, dang, so does this mean this could potentially be unfixable?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it would seem so, this makes me think that this is unfixable.

Comment: @Jammeh Yes, it is entirely possible that the issue is unfixable and is a dead disk.  Without SMART data from your drive, etc. we can't tell, but usually I/O errors which start to randomly crop up one day and persistently freeze or break the system tend to suggest a dead or dying disk

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the one USB/CD boot disk is handy. http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/ You can do a diagnosis and salvage your document or try to clone your entire disk into a new disk, and etc.